# Should I ask for payment for my logo and website design when I delivered them late?

Tags: website-design, logo, business, client-relations, freelance

I have designed a logo and a website for a company.

Because I took a little longer than usual (3 weeks), they are talking about hiring someone else.

I delivered the designs, (10 Logo Designs with at least 50 variations) and a website design. If they hire someone else, all my effort has gone to waste.

**Should I still ask for my payment?** 
I think I should, but not the whole amount as said, like 20% of it.

Please help.

Comment: We can't really answer this specifically, as it all comes down to whatever you and your client initially agreed upon, the relationship you have, gut feelings, etc. In general, however, if you do the work, bill for it.

Comment: *Fifty* variations and a website in three weeks? From one person? That's not long at all. Bill them. Absolutely. For all of it. And don't work for them again.

Comment: I agree with Lauren Ipsum. Charge for every minute.

Comment: "Lil longer than usual" --- did you miss any agreed deadlines? Sounds like they're past clients since you say it took longer than usual, in the past how long did it take? If every time you worked for them you did it a few days and this one took a few weeks I might offer them a discount to keep them as clients. I'd still charge them though.

Comment: This sounds like a client who doesn't know what they want, but wants to exhaust the universe of possibilities. Fire them. After you get paid.

Comment: Other answers have pretty much said it, but I'll add this for consideration: in what other industry can a client hire a consultant for an indefinite amount of work and later decide to pay them only if they like the results? Can I hire someone to re-tile my bathroom and then not pay because I decide I don't like the color? Can I hire the neighbor kid to cut my grass, force him to redo it twice, and then refuse to pay him because he took too long? No. If they think you're too slow for them, their remedy is to not hire you again. Which sounds like it might be good for you.

Comment: I've only fired 2 freelancers.  One ignored my requirement that they not touch a production environment, and the other failed to respond to communication for an entire week.  If you delivered, even if it was late, and as long as we were in contact, I'd expect to have to pay you...So did you tell them you were going to be delayed?

Comment: Absolutely yes. And bill for the full amount. See also: [Fuck you, pay me](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jVkLVRt6c1U).

Comment: Go to this guy and tell him he should give you your money. If you show the right attitude he will pay. Note that, following the rules of the industry there are some levels of escalation: From friendly asking to cutting fingers.

Comment: The company's size and/or sense of design should not be relevant to the question. I recommend removing that sentence.

Comment: YES. You should bill them the entire amount. Do _not_ give them a discount _before_ that. If they kick up a stink, you _might_ go down a little, but do not start out with giving a discount. I am actually a little concerned about the fact that you did 50 variations. Does this mean 50 _different_ logo ideas, or 50 iterations of the same basic idea? It sounds like an exhausting process and might have contributed to a sense of "unprofessionalness".

Comment: Put number of change rounds in the contract. My wife does freelance graphic design, and has yet to go over budget because she gets everything specified up front. :)

Comment: Thanks to all of you for this overwhelming response. I'm going to ask for my full payment now. And thanks to each one of you, I will be full of words. I worked hard on this project.

Comment: ...and? Any luck?

Comment: Thanks to all of you for the advice. I got paid yesterday. Half of it. $166, I have agreed for the rest of the $116 payment in a few weeks. Big thanks to all of you :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Depends on your contract.

In general, absolutely, yes. You did the work, you provided it to the client, now their job is to pay you. I would not offer a discount (seriously, 50 variations?) but would keep it in mind for negotiation if needed. Given that you did so many variations, I would probably offer a 20% discount at most, but only if they were extremely hesitant at paying the invoice. In reality, I wouldn't be happy with a discount - the work was done, after all.

In the future, though, I would suggest having a contract in place that specifies how many rounds of edits/variations/etc you would do. I would also specify that copyright of the intellectual property doesn't transfer until the invoice is paid in full. That way, they can't legally use any unpaid artwork. Spell things out in the contract as clearly as possible so that there aren't any surprises for either of you.

Answer (score 11):

Well, it is hard to say specifically, because such conditions need to be negotiated before the work, not after project dismissed or finished. But, for sure, you can protect all intellectual property you did and client can't use any of your ideas or sketches without payment.

So, you can try to negotiate sell of your concepts, otherwise notify to complete prohibition for any future usage.

Answer (score 7):

Try to make a working timeline and specify price for every step your design goes through: sketching process, variations, meetings, discussions, final design. So the client can follow the process.
Vnovak gave the most efficient answer for now. Also respect for your clients is the basement for success. Your main purpose is to understand their desires and as a professional fulfill them in the language of design.

Answer (score 3):

Man, you are not their slave! Ethics are good but don't compromise on your abilities. You've worked for them. I know how much time it would have taken by "50" revisions. If you think you have done a good work(you are satisfied with what you did) do ask for payment.

Its always better to understand the background of your client. If you know they are from a specific region where people don't bother themselves what the designer has created, be ready to face these kind of situations. I would like to recommend you study some Human Psychology and Geography, i know it will not help directly. But eventually it will help for long terms.

Answer (score 3):

You should ask for payment, and even consider legal actions if they refuse. Even if you didn't have a contract, clearly there was a verbal agreement (after 50 variations it's hard to deny that there was one). In Canada and U.S. you can take them to small claims court and argue your case. "Being late" is not a reason to cancel the agreement.

Comment: In the UK, "being late" **is** a reason to cancel the agreement, once time is made of the essence. However, in this case, it appears *that* will be difficult to prove, while the absence of an agreement will be even less easy; no-one does fifty variations pro-bono.

Comment: If there was a specified deadline, even in a verbal agreement, going past it **is** a **breach of contract terms**. Breaching contract terms does provide grounds for terminating the contract but then the specifics would need to be thrashed out in civil court on a case by case basis, to determine who is liable for what. I'm guessing they would be liable for at least partial payment, but the length of time and court fees probably make that a last resort for any freelance designer. My point is that breaching an agreement does not necessarily render it null and void, it just affects your rights.

Answer (score 3):

If you order something from amazon and it arrives a few days late, that doesn't mean you get the book for free. You could return the book to Amazon, but in your case your designs are custom made, so they can only 'return' them if they are obviously not as promised.

They are only entitled to a discount if you agreed on a deadline and you explicitly agreed that your payment was dependent on making that deadline. Or if they explicitly told you to stop working because they had decided to hire someone else, they don't have to pay you for whatever work you did after they told you to stop.

You could argue morally that if you promised to have it all ready in one week, but took three due to hanging out at the beach for two weeks, and that delay cost them money, then you might give them a discount.

But as far as the legal side goes, all a debt collector needs is confirmation that they ordered something from you, that you delivered it, and that they haven't paid what you invoiced them.

Answer (score -1):

The only way you couldn't is if there was a written contract prior. I would discount it in good faith however.

Answer (score -2):

Obviously you must ask! If work has got delayed, there must be some reasons behind it.

Answer (score -3):

nope. you cant do the work on time, don't bid. this is just one of those "programmers" that low ball to get the work and it backfired.